# Oracle Open Cursor For doesnt do %rowcount

Tags: oracle, cursor

Here is the pseudo-code which is in a stored procedure

```
io_cur  ref cursor

calls package to audit data
open io_cur for select * from table
calls package to end audit io_Cur%rowcount
```

The issue is even though the `io_cur` has not returned all the data the code immediately goes to the last line of the code so the `io_cur%rowcount` is always 0.  I would think before executing the last line of code it would complete the `io_cur`.  Any insight on why this maybe happening would be a great help.

```
Create or replace procedure Run_report (
io_cur  ref cursor
) is 
BEGIN
     ct_xfer.pkg_Common.Insert_log(parameters )
     open io_cur for select * from table
     ct_xfer.pkg_Common.update_log( io_Cur%rowcount)
END:
```

Comment: You haven't fetched any rows from the cursor, at least in your pseudocode - you have only opened it. Does your real code have a loop to fetch and do something with the data returned by the cursor?

Comment: There's a simple little example of using a ref cursor to retrieve data here - https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets .

Comment: Oracle has no idea how many rows can be fetched from a cursor until the last row is fetched.  So `%rowcount` will only be populated once you've fetched the data.  But it appears that your goal is to return a cursor (I assume io_cur is defined as an OUT parameter in reality, otherwise opening it would be problematic) in which case if you fetch the data, you won't have anything to return.  You'd probably want to have the caller log the number of rows fetched rather than having the `run_report` procedure generate that log.

Comment: Hey everyone thanks for the responses.  This stored procedure is for a report being run in BI Publisher.  I am a sql server guy getting familiar with Oracle and BIP.  Okay  how would I have the caller log the rows fetched from the stored procedure if it is only returning the query results.